# TYPO3 Gridelements render FAL Image using Fluidtemplate

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions, fal, tx-gridelements

I'm using `TYPO3 8.7` and the latest extension `gridelements` (8.2.3). Now I want to show/render an image in my `FLUIDTEMPLATE`.. - but I don't know how?!?

Here's my TypoScript:

```
tt_content {
    gridelements_pi1 = COA
    gridelements_pi1 {
        20 {
            10 {
                setup {
                    SectionColoured < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
                    SectionColoured {
                        cObject = FLUIDTEMPLATE
                        cObject {
                            file = EXT:myext/.../SectionColoured.html
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I upload an image (e.g. for background-image) via flexforms, like this:

```
<backgroundimage type="array">
                        <TCEforms type="array">
                            <label>LLL:EXT:autefa/Resources/Private/Language/backend.xlf:gridelements.SectionColoured.flexforms.backgroundimage</label>
                            <config type="array">
                                <type>inline</type>
                                <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                                <foreign_table>sys_file_reference</foreign_table>
                                <!--<foreign_field>uid_foreign</foreign_field>-->
                                <foreign_table_field>tablenames</foreign_table_field>
                                <foreign_label>uid_local</foreign_label>
                                <foreign_sortby>sorting_foreign</foreign_sortby>
                                <foreign_selector>uid_local</foreign_selector>
                                <foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride type="array">
                                    <config>
                                        <appearance>
                                            <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
                                            <elementBrowserAllowed>jpg,png</elementBrowserAllowed>
                                        </appearance>
                                    </config>
                                </foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride>
                                <foreign_match_fields type="array">
                                    <fieldname>image</fieldname>
                                </foreign_match_fields>
                                <appearance type="array">
                                    <newRecordLinkAddTitle>1</newRecordLinkAddTitle>
                                    <headerThumbnail>
                                        <field>uid_local</field>
                                        <height>64</height>
                                        <width>64</width>
                                    </headerThumbnail>
                                </appearance>
                            </config>
                        </TCEforms>
                    </backgroundimage>
```

That works so far. How can I use the image in my FLUIDTEMPLATE? The debugger returns `12` on `{data.flexform_backgroundimage}` ?!

```
<f:debug>{data.flexform_backgroundimage}</f:debug>
<section class="main-content {data.flexform_farbe}">
    <article>
        <f:format.raw>{data.tx_gridelements_view_columns.101}</f:format.raw>
    </article>
</section>
```

Debug `{data}`..  THanks for your help!

```
pi_flexform => array(1 item)
      data => array(1 item)
         general => array(1 item)
            lDEF => array(2 items)
               farbe => array(1 item)
               backgroundimage => array(1 item)
                  vDEF => '12' (2 chars)
```

Edit: image
[image: uid image background image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's funny. If I try it with the TYPO3 Fluid ViewHelper:

```
<section style="background-image:url({f:uri.image(src: '{data.flexform_backgroundimage}', treatIdAsReference: 1)})">
    <article>
        <f:format.raw>{data.tx_gridelements_view_columns.100}</f:format.raw>
    </article>
</section>
```

I'll get an error `You must either specify a string src or a File object.`

Now I use `vhs`:

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}

<section style="background-image:url({v:uri.image(src: '{data.flexform_backgroundimage}', treatIdAsReference: 1)})">
    <article>
        <f:format.raw>{data.tx_gridelements_view_columns.100}</f:format.raw>
    </article>
</section>
```

And everything works .. [here's the view helper reference](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Uri/ImageViewHelper.html) of the `vhs` extension. Thanks for the helping guys!

Answer (score 1):

Since FAL is working with records instead of plain text paths to the image, you have to use the ID of the record to get the actual image file.

Since I am not 100% sure, you should check if 12 is the ID of the sys_file_reference record or the sys_file record used for that particular image before using the usual < f:image> viewhelper either with or without "treatIdAsReference".

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Image.html

If you just need the path to the image and not an image tag you should go for < f:uri.image> instead.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Uri/Image.html

Comment: The `12` is the  uid from the image, I've edit my initial post. There's an error with `< f:uri.image> `.. and with the view helper `<f:image>` I see nothing, with and without `treatIdAsReference`...?! Error `You must either specify a string src or a File object`

Comment: When the ID is shown while hovering the inline record, this is not the ID of a sys_file but of the reference, so treatIdAsReference should be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it some time ago, using the `media` field of `tt_content` instead of using flexform. This solution assumes that

a) you are using a "frontend provider" extension (EXT:yourext) that stores your TypoScript and Fluid Templates

b) EXT:yourext depends on EXT:gridelements

c) In this example, my gridelement object is called `twocolumnscontainer`

1) TS Constants: use EXT:yourext as alternative path for fluid templates, layouts, partials

```
styles.templates.templateRootPath = EXT:yourext/Resources/Private/Templates/ContentElements/ 
styles.templates.partialRootPath = EXT:yourext/Resources/Private/Partials/ContentElements/
styles.templates.layoutRootPath = EXT:yourext/Resources/Private/Layouts/ContentElements/
```

2) in TS Setup, define the template cObject for content grids

```
lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup.cObject =<  lib.contentElement

tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup.twocolumnscontainer < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup.twocolumnscontainer {
  cObject.templateName = GridElementTwoColumns
    cObject.dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
        10 {
            references.fieldName = media
            as = backgroundimage 
        }

    }
}
```

3) In TS Config:

```
tx_gridelements.setup.twocolumnscontainer {
  title = Two columns element with background image
  description = whatever
  config{
    colCount = 2
    rowCount = 1
    rows {
        1 {
            columns {
                1 {
                    name = column 1
                    colPos = 100
                }
                2 {
                    name = column 2
                    colPos = 101
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }  
}
```

4) EXT:yourext/TCA/Overrides/tt_content_element_gridelement.php

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') || die();

call_user_func(function()
{
    /**
     * Limit the number of images in "media" for gridelements contents
     */
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['gridelements_pi1']['columnsOverrides']['media']['config']['maxitems']=1;

});
```

5) Define the Fluid template (I removed the classes so you can use whatever you want, Bootstrap, Foundation...):
EXT:yourext/Resources/Private/Templates/ContentElements/GridElementTwoColumns.html

```
<f:layout name="Default"/>
<f:section name="Main">
<f:if condition="{backgroundimage.0}">
{f:uri.image(image:backgroundimage.0)}
</f:if>
    <div class="">
        <div class="">
            {data.tx_gridelements_view_column_100-> f:format.raw()}
        </div>
        <div class="">
            {data.tx_gridelements_view_column_101-> f:format.raw()}
        </div>          
    </div>
</f:section>
```

I hope I have not forgotten important steps :)

Comment: Hi Riccardo. That looks good, but I use the `media`field from `tt_content`already for a header image. I cannot use it also for a background-image in a `gridelement`. So maybe I will use your example and try to change my setup instead. Thanks for your answer ... but it have to be working with a `flexform`-Image?!

Comment: @user2310852 See my other answer

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<f:uri.image src="{data.flexform_backgroundimage}" treatIdAsReference="1"/>
```

Comment: Hi Riccardo. this throws me an error ` You must either specify a string src or a File object.`.

Comment: umm it is strange because for me it worked fine... are you looking at a gridelement with an image set or not?

Comment: Since 12 would be an ID string that can be treated as a reference, you should make sure that this works. So what happens when you replace the variable with a plain 12?

Comment: Thanks for your help. With `<f:uri.image src="12" treatIdAsReference="1"/>` i'll get the path of my image. An error with {data.flexform_baclgroundimage}?!?!

Comment: Can you do a debug output of that particular field and add it to the description?

Comment: Hi Jo, do you mean: `<f:debug>{data.flexform_backgroundimage}</f:debug>`, that returns: `12' (2 chars)`? You see the data-debug above (see. question).